# Disabling URL editing using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, url, browser, disable-link

How to disable URL editing in browsers (Chrome, Firefox) using JavaScript  when a tab or window opened?
I need this for restricting the user from changing file name in URL from Login page onwards in my application.

New tab or window opens when i click on "Login" hyperlink in somepage.
Best example for this is "Bank Of Baroda Internet banking LoginPage".